# How do I print the node title and body?

Tags: theming

[image]This is the code which I have put in node.html.twig. It doesn't print the body and title of the node, whose bundle is *Basic page*.

How do I print node title and body of a node?

```
{%
  set classes = [
'node',
'node--type-' ~ node.bundle|clean_class,
node.isPromoted() ? 'node--promoted',
node.isSticky() ? 'node--sticky',
not node.isPublished() ? 'node--unpublished',
view_mode ? 'node--view-mode-' ~ view_mode|clean_class,
'clearfix',
  ]
%}
{{ attach_library('classy/node') }}
<article{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
  <header>
{{ title_prefix }}
{% if not page %}
  <h2{{ title_attributes.addClass('node__title') }}>
    <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
  </h2>
{% endif %}
{{ title_suffix }}
{% if display_submitted %}
  <div class="node__meta">
    {{ author_picture }}
    <span{{ author_attributes }}>
      {% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
    </span>
    {{ metadata }}
  </div>
{% endif %}
  </header>
  <div{{ content_attributes.addClass('node__content', 'clearfix') }}>
     {{ content }}
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Is the body field set to be displayed in "Manage display" on the content type?

Comment: yes it is set to be displayed in the manage display.

Answer (score 1):

You can print the node

Title as

> {{ label }}

Body

> {{ content.body }}

Try this,

> {{ content.body| raw }}

It will be used to remove the markup in the content.

Comment: when i use content.body. it prints the body with html tags. for example: i want to print 'lorem ipsum' but it prints '<p>lorem ipsum</p>' . when i put <table> tag it prints that also. I tried node.body.value also it prints the same. what m i doing wrong here?

Comment: Make sure that text format should be full html for body field

Comment: i tried all the three : basic html, restricted html and full html also. I tried removing the tags, then it prints fine for <p> but in some cases i need to make a table. when i use table tag it displays everything in the front end

Comment: Can you send me the screenshot of body field of the node.Please edit the node and take the screenshot

Comment: I have added the screen shot in my question. It shows correctly in the editor. but its outputs this :  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> <tbody> <tr> <th align="left" width="16%">Name of Vessel</th> <th align="center" width="11%">Year Built</th> <th align="center" width="15%">Cargo Capacity (CBM)</th> <th align="center" width="21%">Ownership</th> <th align="center" width="8%">Flag</th> <th align="center" width="17%">Commercial<br /> Manager</th> .......

Comment: I too faced the same problem, when I worked in node.html.twig. This is how, i used <div class = "col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class= "description"> {{ content.body }}</div>
     </div>. Its doesnot show any html tag. Please clear the cache and check it